# Why does the attribute Height has a value * in the following context?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am learning Windows Phone 8.1 on my own. While designing I saw a piece of code somewhat like this in a website.

Can anyone explain to me why the attribute Height is given a value * instead of any numeric value in the following line??

```
<RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
```

Full code is specified below:

```
<Grid x:Name="myGrid">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>                    
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called star sizing (see [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridunittype(v=vs.110).aspx)). It will distribute available space by weighted proportions.

For example:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="Red">
        <TextBlock>I'm 50px tall</TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="Lime">
        <TextBlock>I get 20% of the remaining space</TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="Cyan">
        <TextBlock>I get 40% of the remaining space</TextBlock>
    </Border>
    <Border Grid.Row="3" Background="Yellow">
        <TextBlock>I get 40% of the remaining space</TextBlock>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

[image: Screenshot]